# algorithm to find closest object

Tags: algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

I need to map blue objects to red ones by distance. The center of each object is known. The yellow and green objects, if they are shown, are hints. They help to decide which red object is more important.

For example, in the situation shown in image below:

- The bottom blue object should be mapped to the bottom most right red object since both green and yellow objects are very close to that red object.
- The right blue object should be mapped to top-right red object since it's closer to it.

[image]

I have a naive solution, but I'm not quite sure what to do instead of "????" below

Do you have any suggestions?

**My naive solution in sort of pseudo-code:**

```
for each BLUE:
   find group P=(YELLOW_BLUE, GREEN_BLUE and RED_BLUE) when each object in P is the closest to BLUE
   vector<RED> redCandidates
   for each O in P:
       if O is YELLOW OR O is GREEN
          find closest RED to O 
          insert RED to redCandidates

   if size of redCandidates is 0 -> return RED_BLUE
   else if size of redCandidates is 1 -> return redCandidates[0] since hint has more weight to the decision
   else if size of redCandidates is > 1 -> ????
```

**UPDATE1**
After looking into *Minimum Cost Flow problem* suggested by @ldog, I decided to use *Hungarian Algorithm*. I created bipartite graph where each blue node is connected to each red node and the weights on the edges are the distance between blue and red.
[image]

Now, before I solve the graph, I need to apply rewards on the edges where yellow/green are close to red. I don't quite understand how to do that.
Let's say distance between blue 1 and the red 4 is D_1_4 = 10 and the distance between the yellow hint 11 and the red 4 is D_4_11 = 3. So, because D_1_4 > D_4_11, should I just add reward to the edge 1_4? Or, should I add the reward to each edge that enters node 4, meaning edges 1_4, 2_4 and 3_4?

Comment: Can `redCandidates` ever be larger than 2 (1 for closest to yellow and 1 for closest to green)? If yellow and green have the same significance then take the red closest to blue between the two of them.

Comment: The size of each object is the same. What do you mean, take the red between blue and yellow and green? What if yellow and green are slightly to the left of the most-right red one?

Comment: There may be two reds, one closest to green, and one closest to yellow. Which one to pick? Pick the one that is closer to blue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your question is not fully formed and you are looking for a decent formulation of the things that you expressed in words.

Here are some suggestions:

1. Use intersection over [union](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/07/intersection-over-union-iou-for-object-detection/) for dealing with how to assign similarity for overlapping areas.
2. There are many ways you could try to make what you expressed in words quantified, and therefore able to be optimized. One reasonable way to quantify what you expressed in words is as a minimization problem I will discuss below.

The minimization should assign one blue box to exactly one red box (given what you told me.) The green and yellow boxes are hints and are not included in this constraint, they are simply used to modify which red box is preferential over others. To formalize what you described in words, we have the set of red boxes `R` and the set of blue boxes `B`. There are `m` red boxes and `n` blue boxes with `m >= n`. Each pairing of blue box `i` with red box `j` has a preference `w_{ij}` (this preference is pre-calculated accounting for the hint boxes as well as spatial proximity.)

We wish to compute:

```
           max \sum_{i<j} w_{ij}x_{ij}
 such that 
           \sum_{k} x_{ik} = 1, \sum_{l} x_{lj} = 1, x_{ik} \in {0,1}
```

The variable `x_{ij}` is 1 if and only if blue box `i` is assigned to red box `j`, it is 0 otherwise.

This problem (is [Totally Unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Common_totally_unimodular_matrices)) and can be solved in polynomial time. In fact, it can be solved as an instance of the common [Minimum Cost Flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem#Minimum_weight_bipartite_matching). To do this, define a node in a graph for each blue box `i`, and a node in a graph for each red box `j`. Connect each blue node to each red node (directed blue->red) with an edge with weight `-w_{ij}` and capacity 1. Connect each blue node to the source (directed source -> blue) with an edge of capacity 1 and weight 0. Connect each red node to the sink (directed red->sink) with an edge of capacity 1 and weight 0. Give the source a supply of `n` and the sink a demand of `n`. Compute the Minimum Cost Flow on this graph (see for example [lemon](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon)) and the resulting flow yields the maximum solution (alternatively minimum flow.)

Having described this in detail, I see this is already a common approach [1] to solve exactly problems like yours. [Here](https://github.com/nwojke/mcf) is an implementation.

YMMV depending on how good you make your weights to be. You may want to try a machine learning approach to determine optimal weights using a ground truth dataset and an iterative refinement. The refinement can be computed for a fixed set of blue and red ground truth boxes by refining the weights `w_{ij}` until all other possible assignments other than the ground truth have a lower score of the optimization than the ground truth. This can be done iterative using any max-margin learning framework or technique, combined with the method I described above (and apparently is described in [1].)

[1] Zhang, Li, Nevatia: Global data association for multi-object tracking using network flows, CVPR (2008).

Comment: so, I need to come up with a formula that pre-calculates the `w_{ij}`?

Comment: Yes, or you can apply machine learning to fit it optimally on a given dataset.

Comment: I've updated my post (**UPDATE1**). Can you please take a look?

Comment: @theateist The Hungarian algorithm tries to find the *smallest* value, so if you want something to have a higher change a being selected, you need to make the weight smaller. Something like `w[i][j] = dist(b[i],r[j]) / dist(r[j],nearest_yellow_or_green)`.

Comment: @theateist AFAIK you don't want to use the hungarian algorithm, it doesn't quite solve the problem you want (because you have a different number of blue and red boxes.) MCF is the formulation you want to use, it solves the weighted bipartite matching problem. See this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem#Minimum_weight_bipartite_matching.

Comment: @theateist To answer "Or, should I add the reward to each edge that enters node 4, meaning edges 1_4, 2_4 and 3_4?" Yes, you want the reward to affect all connections. You can think of a case where 1_4 and 2_4 are both very close to node 4. If you want to hand craft the weights, I would suggest you use geometric means to adjust the weights for different criteria. For example for weight 1_4, it can be w_1_4 = sqrt(D_1_4 * T_4) where D_1_4 is distance of 1 -> 4 and T_4 is a reward based on 4 being close/far to a hint box.

Comment: @theateist The hungarian algorithm is asymptotically very slow (O(n^4) I believe), there are faster algorithms now. This link shows the exact formulation of the graph you want to construct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Minimum_weight_bipartite_matching.pdf

Comment: @ldog, beside the inefficiency of hungarian algorithm which I think is O^3, from what I know, it doesn't require to have same number of nodes, does it?

Comment: @theateist Every formulation I've seen of the Hungarian algorithm states the restriction that the bipartite graph must have an equal number of nodes in each partition. For example this is stated on wikipedia under the hungarian algorithm: "In the matrix formulation, we are given a nonnegative n×n matrix, ...". However, you may know of a variant of the Hungarian Algorithm that doesn't have this constraint, which will likely be very similar if not exact to one of the existing MCF algorithms. These are all just variants of algorithms solving a Totally Unimodular Linear Program.

Comment: @ldog, I'll double check that. But, in any case, the way I build bipartite graph shouldn't choose, right? I'll just use other algorithm to solve that graph. Meaning, I can still use `w[i][j] = dist(b[i],r[j]) / dist(r[j],nearest_yellow_or_green)` for weights for edges in bipartite graph.

Comment: @ldog, also what do you mean by `nearest_yellow_or_green`. There can be red boxes that don't have any yellow or green boxes near them, e.g. red boxes 5 and 6. So, the nearest yellow for red boxes 5/6 will be the yellow box 11. Shouldn't I have some kind of tolarance what "nearest" mean or since we divide by `dist(r[j],nearest_yellow_or_green)` it doesn't matter?

Comment: @theateist that wasn't my comment. There are a many ways to hand-craft the weights, it would require experimentation to find which work best. As I mentioned a few times already, an alternative is to use machine learning to tune the weights on a ground truth dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195218/discussion-between-ldog-and-theateist).